# Inserting Large Blocks of HTML without Modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I am performing DOM manipulation and need to insert fairly large blocks of HTML and was wondering if there was a better way of doing so beyond concatenation or a jumbled mess of code.  Take the fairly simple code below:

```
<div id="mydiv">
 <img src="image1.jpg" />
 <a href="page1.html" onclick="myfunction('test');">Here's My Link</a>
</div>
```

I know of two ways to insert the HTML inside of a page – both require manually escaping single quotes:

**Concatenate the String**

```
$('#mydiv').after(  //html, innerHtml, insertAfter, etc. can be used here
    '<div id="mydiv">' +
    '<img src="image1.jpg" />' +
    '<a href="page1.html" onclick="myfunction(\'test\');">Here\'s My Link</a>'+
    '</div>'
);
```

**Remove Line Breaks**

```
$('#mydiv').after('<div id="mydiv"><img src="image1.jpg" /><a href="page1.html" onclick="myfunction(\'test\');">Here\'s My Link</a></div>');
```

My code example is very short but it’s easy to see neither of these two processes scale very well once you get above 10 lines or code or JavaScript calls that have to be escaped.  From a work flow perspective, it is really time consuming to write/test code then manually convert it to one of the methods above.  Furthermore, it becomes incredibly difficult to debug or add code within this jumbled mess on a future date – the line break version is barely readable.

With all of these JS/jQuery enhancements – is there really no way to efficiently account for multi-line strings??  How do people who have to do this on a fairly routine basis deal with this?  If something can’t be done in JS, is there some online tool that will convert code to and from (including escaped characters) one of these options (sort of like what JS minifiers do)?

Thanks

Comment: For this, you should explore base64 encoding and decoding. JavaScript `atob()` and `btoa()` are the functions you would need.

Comment: To add to my first comment, you really should use a javascript MVC framework or create your own MVC templating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**----- UPDATE: -----**

As of May 2014, the new HTML tag `<template>` has been introduced, and is supported by Chrome, Firefox and Opera on desktop.
Check out the status of this tag on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template). The `<template>` tag is one of the new `Web Components`. Use cases may include [Shadow DOM](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/09/web-components/)

**--------------------**

As you wrote, those 2 are possible but quite messy.
Another common approach is to simply include your HTML in the HTML page under a `<script type="text/template" id="template-id">` tag. The browsers won't recognize this as being javascript and so you can simply put your HTML in there. Then you retrieve your template in JS with a simple `document.getElementById('template-id').innerHTML`, voilà!
You could just as well have a hidden div or input with the HTML inside (although this is not commonly done).

Many JS libraries adress the issue you want to solve, which is client-side HTML templates (in your case a very small one). In your case I think the simple `<script type="text/template">` should be sufficient, but for more advanced templating libraries, you could check out [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [Mustache JS](http://mustache.github.io/), or even [dust.js](http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/)

Server-side JS with eg. NodeJS, or client-side AJAX requests allow for external 'HTML partial' files.

Comment: Posted a very similar answer just after you posted yours. Deleted it but [here is the very basic example I included with that answer](http://jsfiddle.net/LLbEs/).

Comment: Good! Thanks for your addition

Comment: @Tyblitz - Thank you for your response.  I think I understand but I'm having a problem getting it work.  Shouldn't something like $('#pOnPage').after('#template-id'); work?

Comment: @user1754738 Yeah but it would be `$('#pOnPage').after($('#template-id').html());` if you really want to use jQuery. Else with native JS you can do  `document.getElementById('pOnPage').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',document.getElementById('template-id').innerHTML);`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem many times. Not only the multi-line, but also the extreme ugliness of creating elements. It makes the code so unbearable..

I'm not sure this is an answer, but what you can at least do is to separate normal logic from 'GUI logic' if possible.

Another possibility is to use **&apos;** instead of inserting a single quote in combination with indenting the html 'strings', like this:

```
var afterhtml   =    '<div id="mydiv">'
                +        '<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image 1" />'
                +        '<a href="page1.html" onclick="myfunction(&apos;test&apos;)">'
                +            ' Here\'s my Link!'
                +        '</a>'
                +    '</div>'
                ;


$('#mydiv').after(afterhtml);
```

This will make the code MUCH MUCH more clear.

- you can see the indentation, what part is inside what.
- separating the html you want to inject from the actual statement also gives clarity (but it will make an extra var though..)

If you use Node.JS you can also use a renderer (like Jade, http://jade-lang.com/) which can render large blocks with ease without the ugliness.

Comment: This works, however read any best practice guide on JS, and you'll see many of them consider it bad practice to include large chunks of HTML in your JS. HTML is intended for structural (elements) & JS for logic.

Comment: true, your method is great! I will use it in future projects. Very good solution, thank you. Also added this in my favorites.